# Python multiprocessing redirect stdout of a child process to a Tkinter Text

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

I'm trying to use Tkinter GUI to launch a child process and display it stdout/stderr output to a Text widget. Initially, I thought the sys.stdout can be easily redirected to the Text widget by setting "sys.stdout = text_widget" but seems not. It comes to an error: "Text instance has no attribute 'flush'".

I checked online and got some solutions, like using a Queue to communicate with the child process. However, none of them fit my case because of my special requirement:

1. the child process should better be launched by "multiprocessing.Process" because it would be easier to use shared variables, which makes subprocess solutions usable.
2. the codes of child process are already there with quite a lot "print" inside, so I don't want to modify them to something like "Queue.put()" or else.

In this case, could anyone come to a solution of getting a "multiprocessing.Process"'s "print" output and display to a Tkinter Text? Many thanks!

An example code of my case is a follows:

```
import sys
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
from Tkinter import *

def test_child():
    print 'child running'

def test_parent():
    print 'parent running'
    time.sleep(0.5)
    Process(target=test_child).start()

def set_txt(msg):
    gui_txt.insert(END, str(msg))
    gui_txt.see(END)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui_root = Tk()
    gui_txt = Text(gui_root)
    gui_txt.pack()
    gui_btn = Button(gui_root, text='Test', command=test_parent)
    gui_btn.pack()

    gui_txt.write = set_txt
    sys.stdout = gui_txt

    gui_root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is still possible to use queues without having to get rid of all of your `print` statements. You can use a `Process` dependent `stdout` redirect to do this. The solution below uses a `Queue` subclass to mimic `stdout`. That queue is then monitored by a thread that looks for new text that gets pumped into the text widget.

```
import sys
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing.queues import Queue
from threading import Thread
from Tkinter import *

# This function takes the text widget and a queue as inputs.
# It functions by waiting on new data entering the queue, when it 
# finds new data it will insert it into the text widget 
def text_catcher(text_widget,queue):
    while True:
        text_widget.insert(END, queue.get())

# This is a Queue that behaves like stdout
class StdoutQueue(Queue):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        Queue.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

    def write(self,msg):
        self.put(msg)

    def flush(self):
        sys.__stdout__.flush()


def test_child(q):
    # This line only redirects stdout inside the current process 
    sys.stdout = q
    # or sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__ if you want to print the child to the terminal
    print 'child running'

def test_parent(q):
    # Again this only redirects inside the current (main) process
    # commenting this like out will cause only the child to write to the widget 
    sys.stdout = q                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    print 'parent running'
    time.sleep(0.5)
    Process(target=test_child,args=(q,)).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui_root = Tk()
    gui_txt = Text(gui_root)
    gui_txt.pack()
    q = StdoutQueue()
    gui_btn = Button(gui_root, text='Test', command=lambda:test_parent(q),)
    gui_btn.pack()

    # Instantiate and start the text monitor
    monitor = Thread(target=text_catcher,args=(gui_txt,q))
    monitor.daemon = True
    monitor.start()

    gui_root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just noticed that the "test_child" output can be displayed in the "text_widget" even when there is no "sys.stdout = q" in that function.

Comment: @AlexZheHu Good catch. I was under the impression that the stdout setting would not be carried over to the child process, but that appears to not be true. You can explicitly redirect the child back to the terminal with `sys.stdout=sys.__stdout__`. It would probably be cleaner to do this with a decorator.

Comment: I just ran your example, but get the following error: `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'ctx'`   What does this mean?

Comment: This is a good answer. Careful, however, with using a `Queue`. It makes properly tearing down child processes a bit more complicated, compare https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.join_thread and https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#all-start-methods (section *Joining processes that use queues*).

Answer (score 1):

The solution given by @ebarr is correct. But it will not work in Python V5 or beyond. You will get the following error when you try to subclass the `multiprocessing.queues.Queue` class:

```
C:\Users\..\myFolder > python myTest.py

    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "myTest.py", line 49, in <module>
          q = StdoutQueue()
        File "myTest.py", line 22, in __init__
          super(StdoutQueue,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'ctx'
```

You need to explicitely provide the 'multiprocessing context' to your subclassed Queue.

Here is the updated code:

```
import sys
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import multiprocessing.queues as mpq

from threading import Thread
from tkinter import *

'''-------------------------------------------------------------------'''
'''                SUBCLASSING THE MULTIPROCESSING QUEUE              '''
'''                                                                   '''
'''         ..and make it behave as a general stdout io               '''
'''-------------------------------------------------------------------'''
# The StdoutQueue is a Queue that behaves like stdout.
# We will subclass the Queue class from the multiprocessing package
# and give it the typical stdout functions.
#
# (1) First issue
# Subclassing multiprocessing.Queue or multiprocessing.SimpleQueue
# will not work, because these classes are not genuine
# python classes.
# Therefore, you need to subclass multiprocessing.queues.Queue or
# multiprocessing.queues.SimpleQueue . This issue is known, and is not
# the reason for asking this question. But I mention it here, for
# completeness.
#
# (2) Second issue
# There is another problem that arises only in Python V5 (and beyond).
# When subclassing multiprocessing.queues.Queue, you have to provide
# a 'multiprocessing context'. Not doing that, leads to an obscure error
# message, which is in fact the main topic of this question. Darth Kotik
# solved it.
# His solution is visible in this code:
class StdoutQueue(mpq.Queue):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        ctx = mp.get_context()
        super(StdoutQueue, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs, ctx=ctx)

    def write(self,msg):
        self.put(msg)

    def flush(self):
        sys.__stdout__.flush()


'''-------------------------------------------------------------------'''
'''                           TEST SETUP                              '''
'''-------------------------------------------------------------------'''

# This function takes the text widget and a queue as inputs.
# It functions by waiting on new data entering the queue, when it
# finds new data it will insert it into the text widget.
def text_catcher(text_widget,queue):
    while True:
        text_widget.insert(END, queue.get())


def test_child(q):
    # This line only redirects stdout inside the current process
    sys.stdout = q
    # or sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__ if you want to print the child to the terminal
    print('child running')

def test_parent(q):
    # Again this only redirects inside the current (main) process
    # commenting this like out will cause only the child to write to the widget
    sys.stdout = q
    print('parent running')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    mp.Process(target=test_child,args=(q,)).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui_root = Tk()
    gui_txt = Text(gui_root)
    gui_txt.pack()
    q = StdoutQueue()
    gui_btn = Button(gui_root, text='Test', command=lambda:test_parent(q),)
    gui_btn.pack()

    # Instantiate and start the text monitor
    monitor = Thread(target=text_catcher,args=(gui_txt,q))
    monitor.daemon = True
    monitor.start()

    gui_root.mainloop()
```

For more details, refer to this topic: [Cannot subclass multiprocessing Queue in Python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39496554/cannot-subclass-multiprocessing-queue-in-python-3-5)